# How to remove quotes from string so that it can be used for an associative array

Tags: javascript, arrays, associative-array

I want to be able to take a string from an array an using an associative array get some statistics for that subject.

```
var subjects = ['Biology','English'];
var HBio = [5.8,8.6,7.4,9.5,10.4,8.8,9.2,9.9,7.2,7.1,7.8,6.5,1.5,2.2];
var h = new Object();
h['Biology'] = HBio;
array=h.Subjects[0];
```

The problem is that the string at Subjects[0] has quotes and so I can't use array=h.Subjects[0], is there any way to work around this? or should I try something else?

Comment: This makes no sense at all ?

Comment: Are you trying to do something like `var grade = h.Biology[0];`?

Comment: OK, My problem is that h.Biology will give me HBio but not h.subject[0] as the word is in quotes, I need to be able to get HBio using the subjects array and an associative array seems like the best way to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want

```
var array = h[subjects[0]];
```

not

```
array = h.Subjects[0];
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/a8j5D/1/)

Comment: Thanks very much, I can't believe I didn't try that.

Comment: To elaborate: You see quote marks, but they are not in the string itself, just being used to set or show you the string value. All javascript objects can use obj.prop or obj['prop'], so given a string propStr, you can do obj[propStr]. If you do h.subjects[0], that is asking for the `0` property of the h['subjects'] object, not the subjects[0] property of the h object.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `h.Subjects[0]` you have write this `h[subjects[0]]` then your code will be

```
var subjects = ['Biology','English'];
var HBio = [5.8,8.6,7.4,9.5,10.4,8.8,9.2,9.9,7.2,7.1,7.8,6.5,1.5,2.2];
var h = new Object();
h['Biology'] = HBio;
array=h[subjects[0]]; //result will be [5.8, 8.6, 7.4, 9.5, 10.4, 8.8, 9.2, 9.9, 7.2, 7.1, 7.8, 6.5, 1.5, 2.2]
```

reason behind this is, when you write `h.subjects[0]`. This means that you `h` is an object having key 'subjects' and which contain an array. But actually we have `h` an object which have key biology and it contain an array of values, whereas `subjects` is an array contain name of subjects. So to get values using both, first we have to get value from `subjects` array like this `subjects[0]` then put this value in `h` like this `h[subjects[0]]`. Now what it will do is first get 0 index of subjects i.e. 'Biology' then get value of key `Biology` from object `h`.
I hope it will clear issue and worth it to you.
Thank you